# Echo PHP inside HTML tag

Tags: php, html

I want to echo this title variable inside the h1 tag, but I get an error message.
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 
  $title = get_field ('page_title');
  if ($title):
  <h1> echo ($title); </h1> 
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: It would help us if you included the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
   <h1> echo ($title); </h1>
```

PHP won't understand the HTML tags so it complains about them.

There are a couple of ways you might do this, but I'd suggest replacing the entire line with

```
        echo "<h1>$title</h1>";
```

PHP will insert the current value of `$title` in the string and echo the result.

Reference: [PHP double-quoted Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 2):

This you code with correcting :

```
<?php 
    $title = get_field ('page_title');
    if (isset($title)){
    echo'<h1>'.$title.'</h1>'; 
    }
    end_if;
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code as per the suggestion, and it is working. I hope it is correct.

```
<?php
$title = get_field('page_title');
if ($title) :
  echo "<h1> $title </h1>";
endif;
?>  

<?php
$input = get_field('input');
if ($input) :
  echo " <a href= 'mailto: ($input)' > $input </a> ";
endif;
?>
```